# How does a C ++ library not be used by another user?

Tags: android, c++

I create a C ++ library and compile it into a file (* .so), The problem is that it can be used by another application if you import the file (* .so) into the project. Is there a way that it can not be used by another application. I tried to find a solution but nothing

**UPDATE**
I can use the signature method to validate my application.

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_myapplication_MainActivity_getSignatureAPK(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    jclass cls = (env)->GetObjectClass(thiz);
    jmethodID mid = (env)->GetMethodID(cls, "getPackageManager",
                                       "()Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;");

    jobject packageManager = (env)->CallObjectMethod(thiz, mid);

    mid = (env)->GetMethodID(cls, "getPackageName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");//
    jstring packageName = (jstring) (env)->CallObjectMethod(thiz, mid);

    cls = (env)->GetObjectClass(packageManager);
    mid = (env)->GetMethodID(cls, "getPackageInfo",
                             "(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/pm/PackageInfo;");

    jobject packageInfo = (env)->CallObjectMethod(packageManager, mid, packageName, 64);

    cls = (env)->GetObjectClass(packageInfo);
    jfieldID fid = (env)->GetFieldID(cls, "signatures", "[Landroid/content/pm/Signature;");

    jobject signatur = (env)->GetObjectField(packageInfo, fid);
    jobjectArray signatures = reinterpret_cast<jobjectArray>(signatur);

    jobject signature = env->GetObjectArrayElement(signatures, 0);
    jclass s_clazz = env->GetObjectClass(signature);

    jmethodID methodId_ts = env->GetMethodID(s_clazz, "toCharsString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    jobject ts = env->CallObjectMethod(signature, methodId_ts);
    return reinterpret_cast<jstring>(ts);
}
```

The function above returns the signature of the application, when debugging the signature is the same but when you Generate Signed APK the signature is unique under key (*. jks), you can use signature authentication method for your application.

Comment: That's the purpose of a library, isn't it?

Comment: He means to say, any C++ module which he wants to protect from being used by other application.

Comment: No, I just want to hide some information @Rohit5k2

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). If you want to **hide** information encoded into your binary, making it unavailable to other code isn't nearly enough. You are going to have to use cryptographic means to keep your secrets private.

Answer (score 2):

Make a function in C++ library to initialize the library which takes the context of the caller application. Get the package name from that context. If that package name does not match with your application throw exception and does not initialize.

Comment: That's the solution, but if an application has the same packagename it can still read the data in the library

Comment: but, you cannot release two applications with the same package name on the play store.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to write a C ++ library that mainly covers information in the application, if a smart user can use that way to get the necessary information. Would be better if it could not read.

Answer (score 1):

You can build the library such that it exposes an interface that accepts a GUID in order to allow access to the rest of the functions.  IF the GUID doesn't match, these API's are stubbed out or you can make them throw exceptions.  Look up exposing C++ interfaces from a library.  As I recall, an abstract interface will work in this case.

Comment: what does it mean GUID

Comment: GUID on windows, or UUID on Linux.   There are small apps that generate these...just google GUID generator or UUID generator on Linux.  They are unique numbers that are very unlikely to be duplicated...they provide a key to using the api.

Comment: GUID's are unique, but they are neither random, nor are they meant to be used as (cryptographic) keys. See [GUIDs are designed to be unique, not random](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120523-00/?p=7553).

Answer (score 1):

Can you compile this into a static library, and compile it into your application? I remember taking this approach when we were running into DLL-hell.

Comment: I can, i will try your way.

Comment: These guys have good ideas if you cannot actually change the library generation to make a static library, and then compile time link your library in.

Comment: I can compile a static library (*. a) and link it to Android.mk, but I do not know how to call a function in my library.

Comment: You just call it. If your library is using global namespaces, it's globally available. If you have it in a namespace, then call it within that namespace. Make sure the .h files are available, you statically link, and your IDE should even offer completion for the function. If it's not available, you'll get a compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that you can't have a 100% protection on your library but you can add more and more difficulties to access to "protected information":

- GUID or licence key
- check the package name
- use an online Key Server
- etc.